# Cart Class feedback

Tags: php, php5

I have written a cart Class, it use session to store data. Is the code well implemented or could been better? You can rewrite my code if you can.

Each item have a number of options with price

Each Option can have many extras or without extras

**For example:**

Item 1 -> (Option ID 1)

Item 2 -> (Option ID 3, Option ID 4)

Option ID 4 => (Extras ID: 1,5,7,8)

```
<?php
session_start();

class Cart {

 private $cartName;

 public function __construct($cartName)
    {
        $this->cartName = $cartName;
        if (!isset($_SESSION[$this->cartName]))
        {
            $_SESSION[$this->cartName] = array();
        }
 }

   public  function addItem($itemid, $optionid)
     {
        if (array_key_exists($optionid, $_SESSION[$this->cartName]))
         {
            $_SESSION[$this->cartName][$optionid]['quantity']++;
            $_SESSION[$this->cartName]['LastUpdated']  = $optionid;
         }
            else
                {
                    $_SESSION[$this->cartName]['LastUpdated']  = $optionid;
                    $_SESSION[$this->cartName][$optionid] = array();
                    $_SESSION[$this->cartName][$optionid]['quantity'] = 1;
                    $_SESSION[$this->cartName][$optionid]['item_id'] = $itemid;
                    $_SESSION[$this->cartName][$optionid]['extras_id'] = array();
                }
     }

    public function addExtra($optionid,$extraid)
    {
        if (array_key_exists($optionid, $_SESSION[$this->cartName]))
            {
               if (!in_array($extraid, $_SESSION[$this->cartName][$optionid]['extras_id']))
               {
                   $_SESSION[$this->cartName][$optionid]['extras_id'][] = $extraid;
                }
            }
    }

}

$test =  new Cart("shopCart");

$test->addItem(5,2);
$test->addExtra(2,10);
$test->addExtra(2,20);
$test->addExtra(2,30);

$test->addItem(5,4);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($_SESSION);
echo "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have been programming PHP since the 1990s and am more than happy to help others to think more about their code and grow as programmers. I love the idea of this site: I would have killed for it when I started!  This is my first post here, here goes.

### array_key_exists() vs. is_array()

Totally optionally, you might consider avoiding `array_key_exists()` in this case and using a shorter hand form of test, like `is_array()`. This saves typing and should be just as clear, though perhaps very slightly slower. Due to the way the English language works, the negative notion `!is_array()` is arguably more readable than `!array_key_exists()` at some subconscious level... but this is hair-splitting. As a dubiously useful fringe benefit, switching to `is_array()` will also make your code self-healing in the event that the structure ever corrupted and a nonsensical non-array value is assigned to a position you wish to access, since the code will then clobber any such non-array value with a new array just as if the array key hadn't existed. (Though, the idea of coding this defensively is pretty useless in most cases and should not really be a huge consideration.)

### Repetition

Your assignment statements are pointlessly repetitive. This is a rookie mistake, and one that is very common to see in PHP codebases.

```
                $_SESSION[$this->cartName][$optionid] = array();
                $_SESSION[$this->cartName][$optionid]['quantity'] = 1;
                $_SESSION[$this->cartName][$optionid]['item_id'] = $itemid;
                $_SESSION[$this->cartName][$optionid]['extras_id'] = array();
```

This could all be replaced easily with...

```
# 1. Create
$cart = array(
         'quantity'  => 1,
         'item_id'   => $itemid,
         'extras_id' => array()
        );

# 2. Assign
$_SESSION[$this->cartName][$optionid] = $cart;
```

Which option seems more readable to you?  Which would you prefer to type? Readability kills bugs, it's a good thing™

### Performance Considerations

Although performance and memory use are of dubious concern to most web applications, it is good to be aware that the second solution actually creates a second instance of `$cart` in memory (one for `$cart`, and one for the part of the `$_SESSION` structure that it is eventually assigned to.)

If performance were actually a concern (hint: it isn't, such tweaks are a waste of programmer time, which is more valuable than CPU time and memory in almost every case) then you could use PHP's 'references' (kind of like 'pointers' in other languages) to maintain the concise syntax but save on the dual memory utilisation. I'm actually rusty on this side of PHP and haven't tested this example, but assuming `=&` is correct then we might create a solution more like this...

```
# 1. Obtain reference
$cart =& $_SESSION[$this->cartName][$optionid];

# 2. Assign concisely
$cart = array(
         'quantity'  => 1,
         'item_id'   => $itemid,
         'extras_id' => array()
        );
```

This solution preserves increased legibility and the code remains concise, whilst avoiding the duplication of our new `$cart` structure in memory.

### Lack of documentation

There are no comments at all.  Code without comments is bad code, and in many companies you would not get away with this. I would recommend at least adding the following at a bare minimum:

- A short description of what the entire block of code does (ie: the cart Class). The notion of 'items' and 'options' should definitely be explored.
- A short description of each function's input (arguments), processing and output (result)
  Whilst some people go overboard writing loads of documentation, a few well-placed and well-written snippets are vastly superior to none at all.

### Architectural Concern: Why OO?

Object oriented methodology is a tool for approaching certain kinds of problems. However, it is not always the appropriate tool! In this case, what do you think would happen if we left it out? Certainly, the code would be more concise without it.

I notice that another response already suggested including the verb Shopping before Cart to impart further information about the structure. This reminds me of both some personal experiences working with people trying to manage scope change on OO code, and comments I read in Peter Seibel's book [Coders at Work](http://codersatwork.com/) where we see quite some number of experienced programmers discussing OO with various perspectives.

At its core, the OO notion is one of abstraction that takes you further from the way code executes on the underlying system, but while this can be powerful many of those experienced persons discuss the problems that maintaining large abstract object systems can have, the notion of a jungle of Class nomenclature and the difficulties reusing such code when large implicit semantic relationships have been created.

In short, have a broad think about whether you want to use OO or not, what it may give you and at what cost.

### Comments regarding previous responses

- I would argue against including a path and file name within your code, since this creates a synchronisation problem when moving files around the filesystem, and really adds no clear value. Any decent editor will give you that information when editing a file, and any good revision or version control systems (RCS/VCS) will also expand short-hand macros to relative path and filename for free.
- Adding a closing tag is probably a good habit as being lazy about such things means, for example, that you can't concatenate two source files without first hacking in the extra tag... a fact that you may forget at a later point.

### Use of magic numbers

You should never use fixed values in your code without explaining their purpose.  Although we see this only in the example code, I don't think it's a good thing™

```
$test->addItem(5,2);
$test->addExtra(2,10);
$test->addExtra(2,20);
$test->addExtra(2,30);

$test->addItem(5,4);
```

### 24 Hour Challenge

- Re-write the code twice, once with OO as an improved `Cart` class, and once without. Include comments that you consider the minimum necessary for another programmer to understand the code clearly. Once you're done, post your improved code.

Answer (score 4):

OK, bear with me here, but the formatting stinks.

I won't rewrite the code for you, but I will continue to provide the information that I can to enable you to do so, should you (based on existing knowledge, or in any of my opinions being finely refuted by others) choose to disagree, then don't implement any of it.

I was about to refuse even to read the code until the formatting (proper indentation) was applied. Formatting is one of the fundamental aspects of our job, yet (seeing as it isn't mentioned as a target of the desired review) is something you are oblivious to, can't be bothered to correct the copy+paste anomalies of, or otherwise have reasoning betwixt these matters that inhibits any action on your part to correct it.

I won't judge harshly, however, so let us imagine you do need advice on this before even thinking about moving on. It is not only necessary to format code in a easily readable fashion, consistency of formatting is expected too; in fact, in this role, consistency to the highest degree possible is of the utmost importance in both **what** is to be done and **how** it is done. What indentation gives us is a clear view of the scope of the code we're currently looking at - without it, or when it is malformed, such can be either laborious to determine, misleading, or irritating *(or any combination thereof!)*

This is why (where curly braces are available for this purpose) I think it is a friendly approach to [start and end execution scopes on dedicated lines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style#Allman_style_.28bsd_in_Emacs.29); meaning, nothing before (other than the proper number of indentation spaces) or after the brace. And it's not just indentation, either: spacing, naming conventions, structure et cetera, all need attention.

On the note of naming convention: Is it a [cart](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/ff/Dockworkers_in_Cap-Haitien.jpg)? Is it a [CART](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CART_%28disambiguation%29)? Oh, it's a [cart...](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/75/Colourful_shopping_carts.jpg)? Reductio ad absurdum aside, I would suggest you name this type (and its corresponding file) explicitly as `ShoppingCart` in order to make clear as to what it actually is.  File size is of smaller concern these days meaning even web-code can speak for itself most times - if size is a concern, then I'm sure you could find a tool for PHP that 'minifies' your release source, still enabling you (and others) to work on self-explanatory code.

PHP [supports composite types](http://giorgiosironi.blogspot.com/2010/01/practical-php-patterns-composite.html) and, by its nature and the nature of the task at hand, you start off using it but fail to extend it to be of any further use (even, if for nothing else, code-readability as mention above.) For instance, a `ShoppingCartItem` could expose the fields that are currently stored in a standard array (which is an error-prone method of doing so too, where maintenance and extensibility are concerned) relating the to actual item. A `ShoppingCartItemExtra` class could do the same for its properties. I'll let you chew further on that.

I'll just assume you were in too much of a hurry to add the ending php tag (`?>`).

I'll leave it there, with scope-formatted version of your code. :)

```
class Cart
{
    public function __construct($cartName)
    {
        if (!isset($_SESSION[$this->cartName]))
        {
        }
    }

    public function addItem($itemid, $optionid)
    {
        if (array_key_exists($optionid, $_SESSION[$this->cartName]))
        {
        }
        else
        {
        }
    }

    public function addExtra($optionid, $extraid)
    {
        if (array_key_exists($optionid, $_SESSION[$this->cartName]))
        {
            if (!in_array($extraid, $_SESSION[$this->cartName][$optionid]['extras_id']))
            {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `I'll just assume you were in too much of a hurry to add the ending php tag` -- leaving off the ending tag is pretty standard practice in a lot of places. Unless you're outputting HTML in your file there's no reason for it and it can lead to accidental blank lines AFTER the closing PHP tag which may cause problems. At my company we usually end our non-view PHP files with `# EOF complete/path/and/file.name`

Comment: For the love of *insert deity*, why can't I find more PHP code that looks like this!  Excellent reply!

Comment: @Erik: Good point, though, since you at least mention a practice of doing so - I tried to skirt around any language specifics and probably shouldn't really have concerned myself with this particular element. @JohnKraft: Thanks.